# Controller can't be found in my require attribute from my directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've this html:

```
<nav>
  <ul rf-hover-wrapper>
    <li rf-hover-child rf-on-hover-class="hover">Home</li>
    <li rf-hover-child rf-on-hover-class="hover">About us</li>
    <li rf-hover-child rf-on-hover-class="hover">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And my directive and controllers:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('rfHoverWrapper', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controler: function (){
          this.onMouseOver = function(el, addClass) {
             el.bind('mouseover', function() {
                el.addClass(addClass);
             });
          };

        }
      }

  });

app.directive('rfHoverChild', function() {
  return {
    require: "^rfHoverWrapper",//here i'm requiring rfHoverChild controller above
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, iElement, attrs, rfHoverWrapperController) {
       console.log(rfHoverWrapperController);
    }
  }
});
```

and i'm getting this error:

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'rfHoverWrapper', required by
>   directive 'rfHoverChild', can't be found!

why this can't be found? I've seen many examples and they work almost in this way.

Comment: Is the `controler` typo posted here also in your code?

Comment: yes, the controller is inside rfHoverWrapper directive.

Comment: Right, but as posted above, `controler` should be `controller`. If in your code, it is `controler` then no controller does exist for rfHoverWrapper and would explain the error you're seeing.

Comment: yes you're right! ow god i've looked for everything in my code... thanks!

Comment: I added it as an answer. Do with it what you will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directive as a typo. `controler` should be `controller`. With the typo, the controller never got registered and thus explains the error you're seeing.